# Long running php script blocks other php requests

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

My flash web application calls php script to upload a document. At the same time, it calls another php script to save some data. The two calls should be independent of each other. However, the call to save data is blocked and is not processed until the first call (to upload) is completed.  Is this the nature of PHP scripts?

[image]

Comment: Are you using session variables? If so, try calling `session_write_close` to release the file lock so the second request can run.

Comment: This is defenetly not the nature of PHP scripts. I have never used flash myself but is it possible that flash itself is waiting for the firts call to end?

Comment: I'm looking at firebug network queue and I see two calls made, one is waiting for another. As soon as first one finishes, the other one starts to be processed. Hence my guess is that it has to do with PHP script.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I am using session variables and call `session_start`. The use of `session_write_close` makes sense, however, when I add it to the script and after it executes, the script is still blocking...

Comment: Where are you adding the `session_write_close`? It should be immediately after you're done with session stuff, before the long-running code.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol correct, that is exactly what I'm doing. Right after I'm done with setting/getting session variables and right before long running code.

Comment: In that case, I don't think it's a problem with PHP. It could well be a Flash limitation. Is there maybe an "asynchronous" setting you might be missing?

Comment: The thing is, I can see two requests that go out(see my updated screenshot). So at that point, flash is out of the picture.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol my apologies for some reason session_write_close fix started to work. Not sure what happened. :-/  Your fix was right all along. Thanks. If you want to post it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `$_SESSION` variables, the session file is locked until the request ends. This means that a new request cannot start being processed until the first one finishes.

To unlock the file, use [`session_write_close`](http://php.net/session-write-close). This will allow the second request to proceed.